# Does OS X limit the memory usage of secondary threads?

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa, macos, exc-bad-access

I have to perform a heavy task. When I run it in the main thread, everything is perfectly fine, but when I try to run the task from a separate thread, the error which comes up is "**No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc**".

I'm using `+[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:]`, and I put the required autorelease pool when necessary (that is, at the beginning I alloc and init it, then at the end I drain it).

My question is: is there a memory limitation (maybe stack memory is cut?) on secondary threads? I have tried to debug with Instruments, however there's no leak, the app just crashes.

Comment: Are you calling **autorelease** before calling detachNewThread? If you are, the object was autoreleased at your main thread already and then you try to access it from the other thread it's already gone.

Comment: @Maurício Linhares No I'm not. Actually, there isn't even one call to -autorelease in the app.

Comment: Why are you talking about draining the autorelease pool? Is this on the new thread? Enable NSZombie on your project and it might help you out -> http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled

Comment: @Maurício Linhares The NSAutoreleasePool is placed in the new thread, and at the end I call -drain. I'm trying to use zombies now, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Maurício Linhares Zombies aren't helping, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you get a backtrace with this error?

Comment: Are you running a loop on the thread? If so, try using an autorelease pool *inside* the loop.

Comment: Use Instruments. For one thing, its Zombies template is better than NSZombieEnabled; for another, its Allocations instrument lets you see your program's memory usage, with and without zombies; for another, it has instruments for monitoring thread usage. **You aren't necessarily looking for a leak;** see what is using all of the memory and make sure you're not spawning off many more threads than you meant to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Apple's documentation, you can increase the stack size using -setStackSize:.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html

However, you'll have to allocate the object in order to be able to set that attribute.

Comment: If the error that he's getting is `No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc`, I am thinking maybe the problem is with the heap. If he was out of stack memory, he would have gotten a stack overflow ;-)

Comment: @Chaitanya Gupta If the heap was involved, I think the main thread would cause the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

i don't know if this helps, but you could try using queues instead of NSThreads. [link to Apple's documentation of "Migrating away from Threads"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1) .

Comment: `NSOperations` and GCD queues all run on threads using the same default stack sizes for threads. So this will not solve this problem, although it is generally a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The main thread has a stack of 1MB, secondary stacks has a default stack size of 512KB.

You will get this error message is you run out of stack space, and since it works on main thread but not secondary I would say that is exactly your problem.

My first advice would be to reduce recursion if you can, since 512KB is quite generous to start with, and incrementing the size will probably only post-pone your troubles. Potentially until the app is in the end users hands crashing wildly for 1-star reviews.

If you do want a bigger stack then you must instantiate, configure, and start the stack yourself. Like this:

```
NSThread* t = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                      selector:@selector(someSelector:)
                                        object:anArgument];
[t setStackSize:1024*1024];
[t start];
```

The minimum stack size in 4K, and the size must by in increments of 4K.